# J2ME - Supporting different platforms in one project

Tags: java, java-me, project

I am developing an app in J2ME which will be deployed on different platforms (That all support J2ME)

For the UI I will be using LWUIT and making sure it renders roughly the same on each platform. (LWUIT is cross platform)

As I am aware that each platform has its own nuances such as the availability/absence of libraries, I was wondering whether the best course of action is to

A) create a new project for each platform (e.g one for Blackberry, one for Nokia) and copy&paste the similar, reusable code between them; essentially maintaining 4-5 similar codebases at once.

OR

B) Have one big project riddled with "if" or "switches" saying (IF platform == x then do xx).

Can anyone tell me if the above has some seriously dumb oversights im not picking up? I am leaning towards implementing A however I think both have some maintainability issues..

Many thanks

Fenix

Comment: Bonus: In a previous iPhone project I worked on, we supported different version platforms using a lot of if statements, so this is where the idea came from

Comment: If I were you,I would do 'A' rather than 'B' because it would reduce the overall jar file size. Moreover,I've seen some [games which are seperated into several jar files](http://www.java.mob.org/game/farm_fenzy.html) depending upon the platform.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Of course with build tools compiling different JARs for different platforms is not a problem. My issue is more of code organization. As for JAR size I do not believe it will be such a factor in this case (thanks to full obfuscation). I will probably go with A though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining multiple codebases is something most developers prefer to avoid.

Afaik most developers instead makes use of preprocessors, which basically allows you to use a lot of if sentences in your code, without making the jar file bigger.

I've used preprocessing in all of my JavaME game projects, to be able to compile to multiple targets with one codebase.

```
//#if ScreenWidth==240
tilesize = 16;
spriteSheet = Image.createImage("sprites16x16");
//#endif
//#if ScreenWidth==640
tilesize = 32;
spriteSheet = Image.createImage("sprites32x32");
//#endif
```

You may not have heard of preprocessing because it's generally not used for Java. But it makes sense to use it for JavaME, because of the fragmentation in devices. I'd love to be able to use preprocessing for Android projects as well, but that's sadly not (yet) possible.

Other minor things, like e.g. the presence of Nokia-UI, wouldn't need preprocessing though. Just use a classForname to check whether the class is there, and set a boolean to true if it is. Then use this boolean in your code to check if a certain piece of code should be executed.
(For example, I use the Nokia-UI API to keep the screen alive, because this API is present on Nokia and Sony Ericsson devices).

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.nokia.mid.ui.DeviceControl");
  nokiaui = true;
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

And then later in my game-loop:

```
if (nokiaui) {
  com.nokia.mid.ui.DeviceControl.setLights(0, 100);
}
```

You **could** put stuff like that in a preprocessing block too, but then you'd miss devices that **might** support it.

Comment: Some very solid advice! I will adopt this strategy (multiple codebases would probably just annoy me after a while). As for preprocessors actually I come from an Obj-C background so I am quite familiar with them however I was under the impression Java didn't have support for preprocessors. Anyway thanks for your response, I will accept your answer.

Comment: One issue i've just run into.. I need to use different JAR libraries (specifically LWUIT) for different platforms. AFAIK in Netbeans its not possible to use preprocessing to designate which JARs to use. Any thoughts?

Comment: Preprocessing will make turn you life to a hell and endless debugging

Comment: To use different JAR libraries for different targets, you must first create the different configurations. Go to Project Properties, and then Manage Configurations. Create a few. Then in Libraries & Resources, you can select different libraries for different configurations.
(And you can use the same configurations in your preprocessing statements).

Answer (score 1):

This is always taft to support several platforms.

You could take inspiration from LWUIT since you already mentioned it (https://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show/trunk?rev=1653). It is huge codebase and it requires time to follow it. The main idea is modularise project and hide platform specific details through interfaces and implementations. And configure it through dependency injections in runtime or compile time.

For example you have `Client` class that will communicate with server through http. So you will probably have next structure:

```
common
  Client
  Network

j2me
  J2MENetwork extends Network
  J2MEMidlet
blackberry
  BlackBerryNetwork extends Network
  BlackBerryApp
```

So the `Network` will be abstract class and will have some common logic about constructing urls with retries. And `BlackBerryNetwork` will do network communications with platform specific API. `Client` will be inject with correct implementation in `J2MEMidlet` or `BlackBerryApp`.

As advised:
1) Do not copy your code. Maintain one codebase
2) I really against preprocessing. So if it is not possible to avoid it at all try to concentrate all preprocessing in one-two factory classes

Good luck and my best wishes!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response! I am considering segregating my class files based off platform and just doing dependency injections when required as you said. You said " I really against preprocessing", why is that out of curiosity? Many thanks

Comment: I'm against everything implicit in the code. Preprocessing is making code complex, is modifying the program flows in not predicted way. It is hard to maintain. It is hard to navigate and follow code especially if you're in eclipse

Comment: You live & you learn. Thanks! And incase it interests you the solution i've gone with is: Make a high level UI version of the app for high memory platforms and use dependency injections for platform specifics. And also make a low level UI version that supports max compatibility. Two codebases but hopefully it covers all the bases. Thanks again